# Getting 502 on gitlab when adding repositories, users or doing other actions

Tags: ruby, nginx, unicorn, gitlab-ci, gitlab-7

Usually fixed by refreshing (re-sending POST) the browser multiple times.

```
# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Debian 7.8
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.1.5p273
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.8.2
Rake Version:   10.3.2
Sidekiq Version:3.3.0

GitLab information
Version:    7.8.0
Revision:   44c69cb
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: postgresql
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    2.5.3
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

The server itself has 4GB RAM available and multicore cpu. The error comes instantly so it does not seem to be an memory or timeout problem.

I posted the bug here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10872 but it was closed as invalid.

I have no clue how ruby works so no idea what I am looking at or looking for.

Comment: From what Nobuyoshi Nakada said on your bug report, it seems like your server is having a stack overflow. Did you modify the gitlab codebase at all?

Comment: I only did modifications similar to: http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2014/custom-gitlab-login-page/ - which only modifies templates and images - also the 502 came already before that.

Comment: Is it possible that you're loading templates recursively in a way that doesn't end?

Comment: Wouldn't the error then come on every page view? It does not, it only appears when creating repositories or adding users (or user login).

Comment: I guess it depends on what templates are modified.

Comment: Turns out gitlab does not like 32Bit Debian 7 - switched to Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and everything workes fine now!

Comment: Great! Please post what you did to solve the problem (use Debian) as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: turns out GitLab **does not run on Debian 7 32Bit** - I can not say for sure, but doubt it has to do with the versions in Debian's 7 repository (which are in general older) as I compiled most of the stuff and with gem it anyway got the versions as defined by GitLab.

Very likely GitLab (or gems it is using) does not currently work on a 32Bit system.